Children's magic/fantasy anthology featuring excerpts from stories like LOTR and The Phantom Tollbooth
I'm looking to find a 'possibly 1980s' hardback book which I read in the UK with a very busy cover of witches and wizards etc.
Inside were excerpts from more famous longer fantasy/magical stories like LOTR and The Phantom Tollbooth (with the latter's excerpt being from the Doldrums chapter).
It was probably aimed at ages 10 and up. Can anybody help?

Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Could you please add a few more details to the question? See the guidance for identification requests.

You say that "from the doldrums" was an excerpt from Alice in Wonderland. Are you sure it wasn't from The Phantom Tollbooth?

Yes, I think you're right .......!

Thanks ! @ClaraDíazSanchez

You can accept an answer (including your own) by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

From the details provided, this might be the anthology Over the Rainbow: Tales of Fantasy and Imagination. This was published in 1984, consistent with the "possibly 1980s" date, and contained excerpts from a wide range of fantasy works, including "Alice Through the Looking Glass", "The Hobbit" (although not "The Lord of the Rings"), and "The Phantom Tollbooth". The excerpt from "The Phantom Tollboth" was indeed about Milo's visit to the Doldrums.
The cover was indeed quite busy, but seems to be mainly inspired by "The Hobbit", rather than containing witches and wizards.


Thankyou so so much @ClaraDiazSanchez it wasn't this book but a very similar one which I've now located !

Glad to help @Angela

Here is a link to the page on Under the Rainbow at the  Internet Speculative fiction Database which has lists the various stories in the anthology.  https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?363195

That link was already in my answer (and it's Over the Rainbow, not Under the Rainbow).


This book is called 'Magical Tales' and contains short fantasy stories published by Marylebone books in 1986.
Also known as 'Over The Rainbow' published in 1983

Yes, the same contents as Over the Rainbow, but with a different cover.

Thankyou for helping me find one of my favourite childhood books ! @ClaraDíazSanchez

This might be better as a link+comment under the other answer, as it's functionally the same.
